# How to declare var like a final if this var was defined in method in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, final

```
final Button Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn);
        Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Some text here"+ Wynik,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But then I'm recived this error

```
Error:(87, 69) error: local variable Wynik is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
```

Wynik is in my

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        int Wynik;
```

And lower in code but in this same class

```
Wynik = 70*RT/100 + tspocz;
```

My final Button is under that code (I'm makeing this app in Android Studio) if that have a matter.

Comment: You should try declaring it final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare Wynik as a class field (outside of onCreate):

```
int Wynik;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
```

Then your click method won't have any problem referencing it.